# How to use multiple exceptions conditions properly?

Tags: python, try-except

I am working with many files and this is an example of a smaller portion. Imagine I have my file names inside a list like this:

```
filelist = ["file1.csv", "file2.csv", "file3.csv"]
```

I would like to import them as a dataframe. If I am not able to do this condition, I would try another way... and if I still don't get it, I would like to add this filename to another list (errorfiles).

```
errorfiles = []
for file in filelist:
    try:
        df = pd.read_csv(file)
    except:
        df = pd.read_csv(file + ".csv")
    else:
        errorfiles.append(file)
```

I tried this code above, but it raises the following error and don't add the file names with error to my list:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'file1.csv.csv'
```

I think I am not doing this try-except correctly. In this example, all these files should be in errorfiles as I can't import them. Anyone could help me?

Comment: You need to add the file to errorfiles in the except clause. The except clause is what is executed when an error is raised. Also you should specify which error you want to catch. In your case `FileNotFoundError`.

Comment: The `else` clause is executed when no exception was catched (everything ok).

Comment: Why don't you pre-test if the filename ends with `.csv`?

Comment: Don't ever use bare except clauses. You know that line will throw a `FileNotFoundError` if the file isn't found, so only catch that error. If you also want to handle the error that's thrown if the csv file isn't formatted correctly, or something else goes wrong, add those errors to your except clause (or create another except clause for that error, depending on how you want to handle it). A bare except clause can hide errors that you didn't expect, or handle errors in a way you don't want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a nested `try/except` for the case where the second file is not found.

```
errorfiles = []
for file in filelist:
    try:
        df = pd.read_csv(file)
    except FileNotFoundError:
        try:
            df = pd.read_csv(file + ".csv")
        except FileNotFoundError:
            errorfiles.append(file)
```